# How to use ForEach with two conditions in c#

Tags: c#, foreach

```
foreach (VXmlNode.VObject func in GetObjectsByPath("Function"))
{
    BooleanExpression fexpr = func.GetPresenceCondition();

    foreach (VXmlNode.VObject Objectparameter in func.GetObjectsByPath("Parameter") && func.GetObjectsByPath("Return"))
    {
        BooleanExpression parapresenceCondition = Objectparameter.GetPresenceCondition();
    }
}
```

As you can see above in the code, I want something like:

```
foreach (VXmlNode.VObject Objectparameter in func.GetObjectsByPath("Parameter") && func.GetObjectsByPath("Return"))
```

in my code, **And** condition cannot be there inside a `foreach` loop but can someone tell me the equivalent of this. Can anyone please give suggestions on how to do it? I am trying to get both the XML objects and do something with them. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do please? Do you have two lists with corresponding items and you want to step through them both advancing each one once each time round the loop? Or are there two parameters for each function? its not very clear what you are wanting. Perhaps show some examples of what you want to do? Given the foreach doesn't do booleans it is unclear what you are hoping to achieve with an AND...

Comment: A `foreach` has _no_ condition, so how could it have even _two_? `func.GetObjectsByPath("Parameter") && func.GetObjectsByPath("Parameter")` looks like you are trying to interesect the two lists, but that doesn't make any sense because you would be interesecting two identical lists. Please clarify what the expected result of this expression should be. Or even better: create a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There is a function that gets objects by paths, I need to just specify the kind I want. Kind is a string Eg:  Parameter , Return.
There is a function Node (Function), where I want to get the Parameter Node and the Return node that is inside it and do something with them.

Comment: @Chris I have edited the question, u may have a look at it.

Comment: @user5440565: I'm still not entirely clear. So you have two lists, lets call them `parameterObjects` and `returnObjects`. Are these the same length lists and you want to match the first object in `parameterObjects` with the first in  `returnObjects` and then the second with the second, and so on. Or do you need to match the first in `parameterObjects` with each item in `returnObjects` and then the second in `parameterObjects` with each item in `returnObjects`, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Use [TakeWhile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548775(v=vs.100).aspx)

From the docs :

```
string[] fruits = { "apple", "passionfruit", "banana", "mango", 
                    "orange", "blueberry", "grape", "strawberry" };

IEnumerable<string> query =
            fruits.TakeWhile((fruit, index) => fruit.Length >= index);

foreach (string fruit in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(fruit);
}
```

So you can add more than one condition `fruit.Length >= index && fruit != "banana"`

Comment: There is a function that gets objects by paths, I need to just specify the kind I want. Kind is a string Eg: Parameter , Return. There is a function Node (Function), where I want to get the Parameter Node and the Return node that is inside it and do something with them.

Comment: so meaning the collection i should traverse is the combination of the two functions? or im wrong

Comment: Yes because i have both of the node objects (Parameter, Return) I want to combine some values (parameter: void , return: int) inside it and then return something , if it has the values i am searching.
Eg: <parameter> void </parameter>
          <return>int</return>

Comment: It's  a big help if you edit your question with example outputs including the expected one. So its easy for  us to figure out. This will not eat your ti me

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the Zip method

```
var integers = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var strings = new [] { "one", "two", "three", "four" };

var combined = integers.Zip(strings, (n, w) => new { Number = n, Word = w });
foreach(var myObj in combined )
{
    //Use it
}
```

Comment: There is a function that gets objects by paths, I need to just specify the kind I want. Kind is a string Eg: Parameter , Return. There is a function Node (Function), where I want to get the Parameter Node and the Return node that is inside it and do something with them.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you are trying to do. The code does not make any sense.

```
func.GetObjectsByPath("Parameter") && func.GetObjectsByPath("Parameter")
```

You have the same code on both sides of the `&&`. Is that correct?

That said, you could try using LINQ SelectMany to flatten a hierarchy or Zip as Luca suggested.

**UPDATE:**

You could use Concat or Union. Zip will also do the trick. Depends on your desired outcome.

```
foreach(var item in func.GetOBjectsByPath("Par1").Concat(func.GetOBjectsByPath("Par2"))
```

Comment: There is a function that gets objects by paths, I need to just specify the kind I want. Kind is a string Eg: Parameter , Return. There is a function Node (Function), where I want to get the Parameter Node and the Return node that is inside it and do something with them.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is *vague* one, e.g. how can

```
func.GetObjectsByPath("Parameter")
```

be a *condition* (i.e. returns `true` or `false`) while being a *collection* to enumerate via `foreach` loop? Nevertheless, I suggest using *Linq* with its `Where` filters:

```
  var source = GetObjectsByPath("Function")
    .Where(func => func.GetObjectsByPath("Parameter")) // condition on func
    .SelectMany(func => func.GetObjectsByPath("Parameter")) // get all parameters flatten
    .Select(prm => prm.GetPresenceCondition());

  foreach (BooleanExpression parapresenceCondition in source) {
    ...
  }
```

Please, notice that you can put as many conditions as you want:

```
  var source = GetObjectsByPath("Function")
    .Where(func => ...) // condition on func
    .Where(func => ...) // && another condition on func
    .SelectMany(func => func.GetObjectsByPath("Parameter")) // get all parameters flatten
    .Where(prm => ... ) // condition on parameter
    ....
```

Comment: you again :3 i will delete my answer again :3

Comment: One is `GetObjectsByPath("Parameter")`. Second is `func.GetObjectsByPath("Parameter")`, so they might be methods of different classes. I'm making a hard guess here, although i agree that it is confusing.

Comment: @user3185569: I try to decipher `in func.GetObjectsByPath("Parameter") && func.GetObjectsByPath("Parameter")` in the question's code. 
if the first `func.GetObjectsByPath("Parameter")` is a *collection* then the second one (after `&&`) hardly can be a condition.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko sorry. I got confused by you not using`func` before it in your answer. You said *hardly can be*, I say impossible.

Comment: @Desperado: why drop your answer? You've demonstrated the *right way* - *Linq* - the actual query, however, requires the edited question.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko cause your answers are high level compared to mine :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you simply want to execute the statment inside your `foreach` loop, i.e.

```
BooleanExpression parapresenceCondition = Objectparameter.GetPresenceCondition();
```

...for all all elements `Objectparameter` that are returned by `func.GetObjectsByPath("Parameter")` *and* `func.GetObjectsByPath("Return")`.

For that you just need to combine (*concatenate*) both lists and iterate over the resulting list like so:

```
var parameters = func.GetObjectsByPath("Parameter");
var results = func.GetObjectsByPath("Return");

foreach (VXmlNode.VObject Objectparameter in parameters.Concat(results))
{
    BooleanExpression parapresenceCondition = Objectparameter.GetPresenceCondition();
}
```